# Declaring class object inside try or outside try? Which is best practice

Tags: c#, coding-style

In my code I need to create object of FileInfo/StreamWriter class. 
It can be done in two ways

```
FileInfo file = null;
try
{
// now instantiate the object
file = new FileInfo()
}
```

Or

```
try
{
FileInfo file =  null;
file = new FileInfo()
}
```

Which one is better? Is there any difference in the way GC will dispose the object?

Comment: _scope_ is the difference between the two examples shown. other than that it's a matter of _preference_  on which approach to go with.

Comment: @Aominè Apart from scope is any difference how GC will dispose. I had a discussion with technical SME and as  per him if it is declared inside try GC will collect the object immediately after execution of try block for disposing. Whereas, if we define outside it will wait for a significant time even after method call is over.

I am not fully agreed with him and as per me if I declare outside then as soon as method execution is over it will be collected by GC.

Comment: It makes no difference, the GC is smart enough to not be confounded by a declaration.  Backgrounder [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. Are you going to need to access `file` outside your `try` block? If the answer is "*no, not in any case*" then declaring it inside the `try` block is a good idea. If the answer is "*yes, in my `catch` or `finally` block or somewhere in the code later on*", then you *should* declare it outside the `try` block.

As to your question about possible implications in perfomance, forget about the issue already.

And last but not least, the `GC` *does no dispose anything*. Disposing and `GC` are two unrelated things, the `GC` has no idea whatsover about disposable objects and the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: @MongZhu hehe, lol.

Comment: @InBetween If I am not using it outside try but declaring outside try block is there any performance difference. How GC will work?

Comment: @RavindraMehta no.